# I need help getting a javascript function to execute in correct order

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I am having trouble grasping how to make this bit of code execute in the correct order:

```
window.writeData=function() {
  console.log('this works.');
  push(ref(db), {
          First_Name: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
          Last_Name: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
          Street: document.getElementById("street").value,
          City: document.getElementById("city").value,
          State: document.getElementById("state").value,
          Zip: document.getElementById("zip").value,
      }

  );
  window.location.href = 'calendar.html';}
```

What's suppose to happen is when a button with `onclick="writeData()` is pressed the various values gets written to the database and then the `calendar.html` page is loaded.
However, as it is right now no data is being pushed to the database. I'm assuming its because the `window.location.href = 'calendar.html';` is being executed first.

How do I prevent this?  I've been trying to figure out if `callback()` or `setTimeout()` is the way to go, but I can't get anything to work properly.

Comment: What is `push()`? If it's asynchronous, you need to do the redirect in its callback function that runs when the query is done.

Comment: wrap the function with async  then await the push()

Comment: `push()` is for the Google Firebase database. It's the command to send the data to the database declared in the `const db`.

Comment: `push(...).then(() => window.location.href = ...)`

Comment: @Barmar

That worked, Thanks!  I was so caught up trying to figure out callbacks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.